# Find a subset of input data space with high classification accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms, subset

I'm having what would seem to be quite a general and widely applicable problem but I can't find literature on the subject.

Example problem: Imagine I have medical records of thousands of patients (including binaries such as smoker/nonsmoker, continuous variables such as age, height, blood pressure, categoricals such as occupation, why they have previously been admitted to hospital etc.), and I am building a classifier (Logistic regression, random forest, whatever) to tell me which ones have a particular disease. As it turns out, this classifier is not so good over the whole data set. However, there may be a contiguous sub-set of the input space in which the classifier is much better, e.g it is good at predicting amongst those who are non-smokers between the ages of 25-50.

Another example: Perhaps I have supermarket data (what groceries everyone buys and at what time) and I want to get into the insurance business. So I link my data to insurance records. Here I want to find a subset of customers in my database which I can predict they have a low incidence of claiming on insurance.

**Is there a general technique used to identify the subspace of input data over which we have a high accuracy classifier?** Alternatively do people just brute force the problem? Is there a literature I should be looking at? Obviously the solution needs to weight against overfitting by selecting too narrow a subspace, and there will be some compromise between classification accuracy and size of the input data subset chosen.

Edit for clarification of question:
I am not looking for variable/feature selection, e.g. which variable is the best (or most informative) to use to train a supervised classifier. I want to know how to select the largest region *within each feature or combination of features* in which I have high classification accuracy. E.g. I already know that age (continuous variable) and smoker (yes/no) are important features but I would like a method to select the largest contiguous region, e.g. 32-51 years old, but only for non-smokers, in which i have a "good" classification accuracy.

Comment: Try logistic regression?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Do you mean a logistic regression on the accuracy of the normal logistic regression? That's a nice idea. (although I wonder if I get any new information at the second level?)

Comment: NO. YOU ask  **Is there a general technique used to identify the subspace of input data over which we have a high accuracy classifier?**  Logistic regression gives this information, it is the subset where the estimated risk (probability from logistic regression) is sufficiently far away from 0.5

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Well, yes, naturally. But my question was really, is there a general technique for identifying a **contiguous** region which satisfies a certain threshold of probability. I thought there must be a better way than just a brute-force scan.